# How to delete pointer to a class without virtual functions and no inheritance

Tags: c++, gcc, destructor, gcc-warning

When a class has virtual method, you need to write a virtual destructor to properly free the memory in the destructor.

In my case, I don't have a virtual method in the class and neither any sub-classes.

When I compile the program using gcc with "-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor" flag I get a warning.
Rewriting the destructor as virtual indeed removes the warning, but I don't want to rewrite the destructor of the class as virtual since it doesn't have any sub-classes. 
Is there any way to suppress the warning "-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor" and tell the compiler there is no inheritance - sub-classes for this class?
It's not a specific gcc version or gcc question.

UPDATE:
Discovered that my class has inheritance of other class that has virtual functions and thus itself has virtual functions.

The accept answer was that I missed that the class is indeed virtual (since it inherits another class with virtual functions). Since it doesn't have sub-classes and should have ones, I can add "final" keyword to the class to solved the issue.

Simple code example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
    int a;
    virtual void f() {};
};

template<class T> void foo() {
    T *obj = new T;

    delete obj;
}

int main()
{
    foo<A>();
    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
}
```

Adding final to class A - also removed the warning.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a tag for the compiler you're using, as this subject is very much compiler-specific.

Comment: I honestly can't imagine why you'd get that warning if the class has absolutely no virtual functions. Can you please provide some code to accompany your question?

Comment: imho 2-3 lines of code would help. maybe its just me, but I get dizzy after 2 sentences that talk about code already when I cannot see the code

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Unless I'm smoking something I ought not to, I think this has a standard C++ answer.

Comment: Do you declare any methods as `virtual` in your class?

Comment: @Bathsheba - How can you know the compiler's QoI is such that an answer applies, if you don't know that compiler version?

Comment: @Bathsheba Maybe I latched on to that mentioned compiler-specific option a little to much?

Comment: @StoryTeller: You mean should we still be considering C++03 as the default C++ tag? Surely not? I'm an old fuddy duddy but even I use a C++11 compiler.

Comment: @Bathsheba - **Compiler version**. Last I checked compilers provide different support at different points in time, and also have bugs.

Comment: A blind guess: You say your class has no subcasses and doesn't have any virtual functions. But maybe your class itself *is* a subclass and maybe its baseclass does have a virtual function? Then your class has that virtual function, too, even if you don't see it in your class. In that case the base class is to be fixed, not yours. Otherwise it's a compiler bug. This warning must not arise for classes without virtual functions.

Comment: To be clear: the question here is how to rewrite **valid** code to satisfy some compiler writer's notion of good style.

Comment: You are right, it is subclass of SerializableObject (which has virtual functions).
Using final in the class declaration solves the problem

Comment: @AlonLanyado in that case you should accept Bathsheba's answer (click the hook next to the vote count).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark the class as `final` (from C++11).

Then it can't have a child class, so you don't need to worry about the implications of having a non-virtual destructor. A compiler should be aware of that and suppress the warning.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

Comment: _final_ doesn't apply on cats number ?

Comment: @bruno: Alas not, more like `mutable` or possibly even `volatile`.

Comment: Maybe `register` if they have no fixed address ;-)